# How to keep the infromation filled in the form after invalid input

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm try to develop a PHP page to interact with MySQL. For keeping the values in the form after invalid input, I try to use session_cache_limiter('private, must-revalidate') function and header('Cache-control: private, must-revalidate'). however, these two function are all not worked.
All the contents in the form disappeared after the page refreshed. I don't know where the problem appears. Thanks for any help!
this is the session_cache_limiter function code, I add it at the very start of PHP code block, before the session_start function.

```
<?php
    session_cache_limiter('private, must-revalidate'); 
    session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
...
</html>
```

For the header function, I add this in the if-else structure when the invalid input happens instead. So the code is:

```
...
<body>
<?php
if(preg_match('/[A-Z][a-z]*\s[A-Z][a-z]*/',$_REQUEST['name']) != 1){
            header('Cache-control: private, must-revalidate');
            echo "<script>alert('invalid name!')</script>";
            
        }else if(preg_match('/[\w]+(\.[\w]+)*@[\w]+\.[\w]+/i',$_REQUEST['email']) != 1){
            header('Cache-control: private, must-revalidate');
            echo "<script>alert('invalid email!')</script>";
            
        }else{
          ...(the pdo request for MySQL)...
        }
...
?>
</body>
...
```

I didn't attempt to mix this two functions together but implement them respectively. I hope to ask  for some help of what the problems are and how to fix them. Thanks a million!

Comment: Those headers have nothing to do with your objectives. If you want to re-display the entered data, you must echo it in the correct place. Consider also echoing the error messages next to the field in the form, so the user can see all of them at once. Using alerts for that is a bit 1990s

Answer (score 0):

1.You can use ajax so the page will not be reloaded after submit.
2. You can save data filled on sessions.
3. You can save data filles as a cookie.

Only the first one is recomanded but all of them will work.